# What does "sugarboo" mean?

Tags: meaning

Dua Lipa uses "sugarboo" in her Levitating song. What does it mean? It seems to be in no dictionaries.

Comment: I believe a "sugarboo" is similar to a ["sugar pie honey bunch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Can%27t_Help_Myself_(Sugar_Pie_Honey_Bunch)) ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some lyrics to that song are:

> You want me, I want you, baby
>
> My sugarboo, I'm levitating
>
> The milky way, we're renegading
>
> (Yeah, yeah, yeah, yeah, yeah)

This is a slang combination of *boo* and *sugar*, both terms which indicate someone you care about in a romantic way -- lover, girlfriend/boyfriend, etc. This means the same thing.

Boo: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boo

Sugar: https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sugar

Comment: Thanks, is this a work used only in this song or it is in common use?

Comment: Only in that song. I can only recommend using that word in informal social gatherings where people know you are a non-native speaker.

Comment: People often make up nonsense words when speaking to lovers, babies, pets, etc. It's called 'baby talk'.

Comment: @rppkgai what was the non-native speaker part about?

Comment: @PHPst I've met a few people who were not native English speakers but, because of their advanced conversational English skills, I assumed that they were. So, if anyone who I thought were a native speaker to ever say "sugarboo" I would be very confused and amused. But, were a non-native to say "sugarboo", I would just be amused and probably mention that "sugarboo" is a word I've never heard in conversations, movies, or songs, and it has a very strange connotation.

Comment: @rppkgai - native speakers are _embedded in the culture_. When they hear something like 'sugarboo' for the first time, they immediately recognise it as affectionate babytalk. Their brain works something like this: context: pop song addressed to lover + word starting with 'sugar' (or maybe 'honey) + second part nonsensical = babytalk. It doesn't go 'BZZZT! ERROR! NOT IN DICTIONARY!.

Comment: Boo was/is a common word in certain regions and among certain populations. The same thing is true for sugar. Without doing any research, I'd assume that the singer is a black female from the South, US. That's the overlapping point of those two subcultures.

Comment: @FeliniusRex The singer is from London with parents from Kosovo, so you're assumption is pretty far off.

Comment: @PHPst I wouldn't bat an eyelash hearing someone use the word "surgarboo". It's on the same level as calling a significant other "pumpkin", or any other cute term of endearment. I wouldn't use it in a formal context, but among friends it's fine.

Comment: @E.Aigle You did read what I said, correct? "Without doing any research...." Now if I had done some research, I would have been more specific. Nevertheless, that is likely the origin of the word and it was adopted by others from that point. But please, do go on.

Comment: @FeliniusRex No need to get salty, I didn't mean anything mean by it. Just that assumptions like this can be very misleading, especially about the way people speak English as it's such a widespread language.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a way of describing a lover or a beloved in just one word with fondness.